# Which free IMAP-supporting webmail would you recommend?

Tags: iis, php, asp.net, webmail

Considering a machine with IIS 7.5/PHP 5.2/asp.net and mysql/MSSQL available, which webmail would you pick?
Don't think it's relevant but the mail server is installed on localhost, and is hmailserver.

If it's one using asp.net it'd be a bonus, but PHP is ok as well and probably offers more choices.

"Client side" look and feel definitely needed, flash/silverlight/ajax not a problem.

I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122079/any-good-self-hosted-php-webmail-suggestions), but being asked almost 2years ago and being focused on php webmails, I thought that some better option could've been released in the meantime.

EDIT:

Has anybody had any experience with [afterlogic webmail](http://www.afterlogic.com/download/webmail-pro)? Considering this or horde.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but you could try [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) or [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org/). See also [Horde](http://www.horde.org/).

Comment: +1 for Roundecube. I use it all the time whenever I need a web mail client.

Comment: Another +1 for Roundcube.

Comment: I used SquirrelMail until a few years ago (but now I don't use PHP).

Answer (score 0):

For some friends i used horde webmail:

http://www.horde.org/webmail/

It has everything you need from a webmail.